# How to make a list view not "skipping" items by fast swiping?

Tags: flutter, listview, scroll

In my scenario, the Flutter list view should behave like a page view. That means, when you swipe, no matter how fast and no matter how long the swipe gesture is, it should always scroll to the next item.
The code for a snapping list view is provided here: https://gist.github.com/nxcco/98fca4a7dbdecf2f423013cf55230dba

It'll be nice if someone could help me out on this!

Comment: *"In my scenario, the Flutter list view should behave like a page view."* - so why dont you use `PageView`?

Comment: Legit question. The thing is with `PageView`, you cannot show a bit the next page on the side. Of course you can, with `viewportFraction`, but that does then apply to both sides. So you will see the next items of both sides. If you know a way to get around this, please let me know!

Comment: you could make some custom page transitions, something like: https://gist.github.com/pskink/c04de9b3d643b14051a6bca5189985c1 - you would need to offset somehow (by using `Transform.translate` or `FractionalTranslation` or the like) the prev page so that it is not visible while the next page is